# Normed spaces continuity at 0 proof

Tags: functional-analysis

It says for V and V' under two different normed spaces, let T:V->V' be a linear map. Then T is continuous at 0 implies T is continuous. But then they say
''Since  $\left \| Tx-Ty \right \|' = \left \| T(x-y) \right \|'<\epsilon$
 , T is continuous at all y in V ''.

So I dont understand where they have used the fact that T is continuous at 0 as if it were wouldnt we use $\left \| Tx \right \|'<\epsilon$ only to deduce that its continuous at any y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $T$ is continuous at $0$. It means given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that for all $|z|<\delta$ one has $\|T(z)||'<\epsilon$.

Now suppose we want to show that $T$ is continuous at $v\in V$. Given $\epsilon >0$, take the $\delta >0$ above in continuity at $0$. Now for every $x\in V$ such that $\|x-v\|<\delta$ we have 
$$\|T(x)-T(v)\|'=\|T(x-v)\|'=\|T(z)\|'<\epsilon$$
where $z=x-v$.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the sequence definition of continuity, you take an arbitrary sequence $x_n\xrightarrow{\to \infty } x$ and want to prove that the image also converges.
Observe that any converging sequence $x_n\xrightarrow{\to \infty } x$ defines a sequence converging to zero of the form $x-x_n$, but now the above equality shows that the converging of $T(x_n) \to T(x)$ is equivalent to $T(x_n -x) \xrightarrow{\to \infty} 0$. Which is guaranteed by continuity at 0.